# How to use d-none after calling a method returning bool value

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, bootstrap-4

I have a method called IsSaveStock in my _purchaseWayBillDetailLotServices returning a boolean value
I call this method on :

```
<a href="/PurchaseWayBillDetailLot/@detailLots.Id/@Model.Id" class="btn btn-secondary" id="update-button-@detailLots.Id" @(_purchaseWayBillDetailLotServices.IsSaveStock(detailLots, Model) ? "d-none" : "")>Update</a>
```

In view I inject the service :

```
@using IPMMS.Business.Services
@inject PurchaseWayBillDetailLotServices _purchaseWayBillDetailLotServices;
```

According to the returning value it should be display none (d-none) however no changes something is wrong or missing ? above code ?

I can not use disabled because it is bootstrap

I want this to be disappear

Thanks in advance

Comment: not sure what you wanted to express with the [core] tag. Maybe [entity-framework-core]? The [core] tag refers to CPU-cores, so it's totally unrelated to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Put your condition in class attribute

```
<a href="/PurchaseWayBillDetailLot/@detailLots.Id/@Model.Id" class='btn btn-secondary @(_purchaseWayBillDetailLotServices.IsSaveStock(detailLots, Model) ? "d-none" : "")' id="update-button-@detailLots.Id" >Update</a>
```